# Python Multiprocessing: Mapping AsyncResult object with the worker process running the task

Tags: python-2.7

When multiprocessing.pool.apply_async() is called, is it possible to know which worker process is assigned the Task?

I have following code:

```
self.workers = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_WORKERS, 
                                        init_worker, 
                                        maxtasksperchild=MAX_TASKS_PER_WORKER)
self.pending = []
tasks = get_tasks() # keeps on sending tasks what need to be executed
self.pending.append((task, self.workers.apply_async(run_task, task)))

# monitor AsyncResults
for task, result in self.pending:
   if result.ready:
     try:
         result.get(timeout=1)
     except:
         self.pending.append((task, self.workers.apply_async(run_task, task)))
```

I found that some of the worker processes terminates while executing run_task() method and using AsyncResult object there is no way to know if worker process has terminated. So in my case self.pending list always hold the task and result of which process terminated in-between and no work is actually getting done.

A task can take any amount of time. So I don't want to use timeout to assign new process to the task as it is possible that first process might be still running.

Is there a way to know what process is associated with AsyncResult, so that we can check if process is still_alive or a way to get notification in case process terminates?